# .str.contains returning actual found value instead of True or False

Tags: pandas, series, contains

I am using `str.contains` in my dataframe to see if a certain value is inside the values of a Series.

Instead of the output being `True` or `False`, I want to see the actual value that I pass inside the contains.

```
A     B
1   Fer
2   Ger
3   Tir
```

My expected output:

```
A     B    C
1   Fer   er
2   Ger   er
3   Tir  Nan
```

Is there a built-in way to do this with pandas?

Comment: use a conditional : ``df.assign(C = np.where(df.B.str.contains('er'), 'er', Nan)``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) is perfect for this:

```
df['C'] = df['B'].str.extract('(er)')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   A    B    C
0  1  Fer   er
1  2  Ger   er
2  3  Tir  NaN
```

The parentheses in `(er)` are important; they signify a *capture group*. If the regular expression within them matches any text, that matched text will be copied into the output column. If the regular expression doesn't match, NaN is copied to the output column. `.str.extract` returns a dataframe with one column per capture group, so `(er)(abc)(def)` would return a dataframe with 3 columns.